# How can I track the sales rank of an item on Amazon programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've seen several products that will track the sales rank of an item on Amazon. Does Amazon have any web-services published that I can use to get the sales rank of a particular item?

I've looked through the AWS and didn't see anything of that nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to determine the Sales Rank by querying for the SalesRank response group when doing an ItemLookup with the Amazon Associates Web Service.

Example query:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=0976925524&
ResponseGroup=SalesRank&
Version=2008-08-19
```

Response:

```
<Item>
  <ASIN>0976925524</ASIN> 
  <SalesRank>68</SalesRank> 
</Item>
```

See the documentation here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2008-08-19/DG/index.html?RG_SalesRank.html

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked perfectly. I signed up and got an AWS access key, switched out the ItemId and i'm in business.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon have changed their API so it now requires a signature: http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/ann.jspa?annID=483 so the above example no longer works from August 2009 onwards.